# Visual Studio Code stuck on "Initializing Flutter"

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, initializing

I've just started a self-study course for Flutter (note I have no programming experience so you'll really need to dumb down your responses to me lol), and in Visual Studio Code when I select "Run without debugging" under "select environment" dart and flutter is not available. Dart and Flutter are installed, as is Android Studio with the relevant requirements, so I think it may have something to do with the "Initializing Flutter" message which never seems to resolve.

[Image showing Visual Studio Message in bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62s0C.jpg)

As requested, here is my flutter doctor -v output in CMD- note I have the relevant plugins installed in Android Studio even though it is saying I haven't. I have uninstalled and then reinstalled the plugins with the with flutter doctor doctor showing:
[Flutter Doctor -v results in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiVlr.png)

Any advice (suitable for a total beginner!) greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: I have edited the first post to include an image link and explain that I have the plugins installed (although it shows them as not).

Answer (score 0):

When you start the AndroidStudio Menu, click on Confuguration -> Settings -> Plugins  and type 'flutter', then install it and reboot, it'll fix your problem.