# Initializing Flutter. This may take a few minutes on vs code

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Initializing Flutter. This may take a few minutes takes forever and stops all other processes. any idea on how to solve this?[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: what is your system config ?

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181752/flutter-initializaiton-in-vscode and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579300/visual-studio-code-stuck-on-initializing-flutter

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by killing all dart processes by running the command

```
killall -9 dart
```

- delete the pod files
- run flutter clean